# How to know what parameters are available in a callback function? Javascript, MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am a beginner in JavaScript and web development in general. I've been studying by myself and have hit numerous roadblocks along the way.

Right now, I am very confused about functions with callback functions and its parameters. I have read documentations about these but they are currently too high level for me. I just have a few questions based on the two code snippets below.

1. How do I know what parameters are available in the callback functions? In **#1**, **#2** and **#3**, they have different second parameters and in **#4** it has no second parameter.
2. Is `err` argument always in the first parameter when you have more than 1 parameters? Can I choose not not have an `err` parameter? Can I choose so that `err` is not the first parameter?
3. How do I know if a function can have a callback function?
4. Lastly,  I do not understand why in **#99.1**, `callback(result)` has an argument of `result` when the callback function in **#99.2** is just `function() { client.close() }`? Why not just `callback()`?

Advanced thank you to anyone who will provide an idea about this! Thank you! Any reference, guide or tutorials would be a huge help.

Here are the code sources.

[First code snippet source (Insert a Document)](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.7/quick-start/quick-start/)

[Second code snippet source (collection example)](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/Collection.html)

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const test = require('assert');
// Connection url
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
// Database Name
const dbName = 'test';


// Connect using MongoClient
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {      <-------------------- #1
  // Create a collection we want to drop later
  const col = client.db(dbName).collection('createIndexExample1');
  // Show that duplicate records got dropped
  col.find({}).toArray(function(err, items) {      <-------------------- #2
    expect(err).to.not.exist;
    test.equal(4, items.length);
    client.close();
  });
});
```

```js
const insertDocuments = function(db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
  const collection = db.collection('documents');
  // Insert some documents
  collection.insertMany([
    {a : 1}, {a : 2}, {a : 3}
  ], function(err, result) {       <---------------------- #3
    assert.equal(err, null);
    assert.equal(3, result.result.n);
    assert.equal(3, result.ops.length);
    console.log("Inserted 3 documents into the collection");
    callback(result);          <----------------------- #99.1
  });
}



const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'myproject';
const client = new MongoClient(url, {useNewUrlParser: true});

// Use connect method to connect to the server
client.connect(function(err) {         <---------------------- #4
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);

  insertDocuments(db, function() {      <------------------------ #99.2
    client.close();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is usually to consult the documentation.

The MongoClient.connect() [doc](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/MongoClient.html#connect) (both #1 and #4) takes a callback function of type `Callback<MongoClient>`:

```
connect(callback: Callback<MongoClient>): void
```

And the Callback [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/modules.html#Callback) is:

```
Callback<T>: (error?: AnyError, result?: T) => void
Defined in src/utils.ts:36
Type parameters

T = any

Type declaration

(error?: AnyError, result?: T): void
MongoDB Driver style callback

Parameters

Optional error: AnyError

Optional result: T

Returns void
```

Similarly [toArray](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/FindCursor.html#toArray):

```
toArray(callback: Callback<TSchema[]>): void
```

and [insertMany](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.1/classes/Collection.html#insertMany):

```
insertMany(docs: OptionalId<TSchema>[], options: BulkWriteOptions, callback: Callback<InsertManyResult<TSchema>>): void
```

For 99.1 the `insertDocuments` function was written to pass the result via callback

99.2 called insertDocuments, but apparently didn't care whether it succeeded or not, so it chose to ignore the result.

Comment: ``Callback<T>: (error?: AnyError, result?: T) => void``
This means that ``error`` and ``result`` is a parameter here, right?